# Matching and removing twitter hashtags in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to remove the # character from hashtags only if the hashtag is anywhere but at the end of the string. Examples:

> I'm going to #Disney this month! #WDW
>
> I'm going to #Disney this month. #WDW #Orlando
>
> I'm going to #Disney this month #WDW #Orlando

They need to be converted to:

> I'm going to Disney this month!
>
> I'm going to Disney this month.
>
> I'm going to Disney this month

This code will remove all # characters:

```
function remove_hashtags($string){
    $result = preg_replace('/#([\w-]+)/i', '$1', $string);
    return $result;
}
```

...but before that, the hashtag (or group of hashtags) at the end of the string need to be removed.

Comment: Be careful using this consider a string with entities that will be removed I&#039;m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
function remove_hashtags($string){
    return str_replace('#', '', 
        preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $string));
}
```

I assume here you just need to remove all '#' characters - and not just the ones followed by "hashtag identifier candidates" (= matching the `[\w-]+` pattern).

If that's your task, the code should be adjusted accordingly:

```
function remove_hashtags($string){
    return preg_replace('/#(?=[\w-]+)/', '', 
        preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $string));
}
```

I've replaced capture group with lookahead here. Also, `/i` modifier is not required in both cases: `\w` special character covers both `a-z` and `A-Z` ranges.

Comment: This also removes entities like &#039;